# Send an e-mail to the same e-mail address to which multiple records are associated in a custom object in Eloqua Marketing Cloud

Tags: eloqua

I would like to send several dems to an e-mail address with different customizations based on the information present in a Custom Object.
Es.
Email Address = xxx@x.com
Custom Object:
3 records with different information to be printed in the email to be sent.
Is there a way to ensure that multiple emails can be sent to an email address simultaneously with different customizations?
Is there a workaround for last created field merge etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Create a dynamic for each demo, create decision steps on the canvas which check to see if the field in the cdo has the correct value, if not pass it to the next decision step.. if yes, pass it to the email which passes to the next decision step, like this:
[Multi step campaign canvas example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFGq1.png)